# Creating Thiessen polygons gives ArcGIS ERROR 000537 error in converting points to Voronoi Polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, voronoi-thiessen

I have a problem with creating Thiessen polygons for a set of points. I am creating them with Create Thiessen Polygons tool in ArcGIS 10.1). I am able to create them in a few steps (for parts of the data) but I would like to create it at once.
The error I get is:

> ERROR 000537 error in converting points to Voronoi Polygons

It doesn't say much, when click at the error in arcgis help I found this message:

> Description
>   A TIN surface is created from input points and is used to generate the output Thiessen (Voronoi) polygons.
>
> Solution
>   Check the input point features and make sure that features exist in this particular feature class. As well, make sure that if the extent environment is set, the input point features do not fall outside their coordinate range.

But if it works "partially", where the problem may be?

Comment: You may have some errant points that fall out of the tool's extent capabilities, or there may be some other issue with the feature class.  You might look at the feature class and see if there are any obvious issues, and/or attempt to repair geometry, or export the feature class to see if that fixes something. Lots of possibilities.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer. I will try it. I also thought there may be something wrong "between" some objects as it works when split in parts but does not want to work as a whole set :(. What kind of other obvious issues do you mean?

Comment: Ensure that you don't have duplicate points.

Comment: Are you in a projected coordinate system or a geographic one? Per the [help file](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001m000000), "This tool may produce unexpected results with data in a geographic coordinate system since the Delaunay triangulation method used by the tool works best with data in a projected coordinate system."

Comment: As above or you may have some points that lack geometry. You can find these easy enough if you have completely unattributed rows in the Attribute Table (not a guarantee but a sign of accidental creation which can happen in ArcGIS and is a bug IMNSHO). Cf. the Tools - Repair/Check Geometry.

Comment: Hi, following the advice I have checked the point features. It seems I have no points without geometry. I have also checked them by the usage of the tools: Multipart to single part (data management tools) - as the number of objects is the same for input and output, I guess it is ok. I am working in a projected coordinate system (I have

Comment: I am working in a projected coordinate system (I have set up a coordinate system through- layers - properties-coordinate system. However when I add any feature classess ArcGIS gives a worn that they will not be projected. Shouldn't they be put in the ArcMAP defined coordinate system on the fly by ArcGIS?When I exported the feature class to another place, thiessen polygon tool ends with success but I can not find or display the file.

Comment: Ok, I have created new personal db, set up appropriate coordinate system, exported feature class. This time I avoided messages about features not being projected. I will check the Thiessen and update the issue.

Comment: It is best to edit your question to provide details and clarification - for example you should add the checks/results information from your comments to the question. The projection issues are a whole other question/issue with a few possible causes. It sounds like you set a dataframe projection, but the resulting error would seem to indicate that the layers you were trying to add had no defined projection or the datum of the projections (dataframe vs data) was different and you would need to specify a Transformation for on-the-fly reprojection to use.

Comment: Hello, I have solved the problem finally...:). It seems that while importing my point features class to ArcMAP, even if I set up appropriate coordinate system the points still lack the reference.

Comment: Creating a personal database with defined coordinate system, then dataset with again defined coordinate system and exporting there point feature class - solved the problem. The feature class is now in appropriate coordinate system and Thiessen polygons are possible to create.

Comment: @ChrisW I think you or Izabela should write up an Answer on this one so that the trail of Comments can get some closure

Comment: @PolyGeo I can try, but it seems to me she really worked it out on her own (I'm still not clear on why the points didn't have a projection) and should combine all of her comments into an answer, so I'll delay until tomorrow before doing so to give her the opportunity.

Comment: Hi, here is maybe more clarification of the problem and the answer. Sorry for the confusion. And actually Chris comments were very helpful.

Comment: I have read the data at the beginning from the shp files, they were not in a personal database. I loaded them to ArcMAP and set up appropriate coordinate system that I needed in ArcMAP. Then I added the points from shp. ArcMAp worned me that the points lack spatial reference so they will be added but not projected. (But I thought that if I have set up coordinate system in ArcMAP dataframe, it should work also for points). But the points still were not projected. So, I created new perosnal database and a dataset with appropriate projection and exported points there.

Comment: When I exported points to the dataset with the appropriate projection the points were also projected finally. And the Thiessen polygons were created. The problem was my point feature class was not projected at first.

Answer (score 1):

Several comments have good suggestions to check for duplicate points stacked atop each other and points with no or bad geometry. However the statement in the question that the tool worked partially cued me to take a look at the [help file](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001m000000) where I noticed the following:

> This tool may produce unexpected results with data in a geographic
>   coordinate system since the Delaunay triangulation method used by the
>   tool works best with data in a projected coordinate system.

Based on that I questioned which coordinate system you were working in. In your investigations it appears you found that your points weren't projected *at all* which would probably lead to similar behavior. Apparently getting the points into a proper projection solved the issue with the tool.

---

I do want to point out a couple of things regarding projections in ArcGIS, just for clarification:

- From your comments, the original points were in shapefile format.
  There should have been a .prj file among the files comprising the
  shapefile. If it was missing or damaged, that would lead to the issue
  and warning you got when you tried to add them to a map.
- The Dataframe (with a default name of Layers) can have a projection
  set in its properties. This can differ from the projection of the
  individual datasets added to the dataframe. ArcGIS reprojects those
  individual layers/datasets on the fly to whatever projection the
  dataframe is using *if it can*. It can't if there isn't one defined
  in the first place - it knows what to project *to* because of what
  you set the dataframe to, but it doesn't know what to project *from*
  because the data doesn't say. It's like saying 'can you give me 532
  in meters?' 532 *what*?
- Projections also involve Datums, and ArcGIS handles them in separate
  steps. If the datum between two projections doesn't match, you must
  specify an appropriate transformation to use when converting between
  them or your points may end up in entirely the wrong place. You can't
  just pick the projection you want to use, you must specify both
  (though it's in the same dialog box).
- Geodatabases *themselves*, be they file or personal, don't have
  projections/coordinate systems. It's the individual feature classes (or feature datasets) *inside* the geodatabase that do, and you *can* have several feature classes with *different* projections/coordinate systems *in the same geodatabase*.
- You should be cautious about just 'defining' the CRS of an unknown
  dataset (which is essentially what you did with the export). If you
  don't know what it was really in, you have to check that it's coming
  in 'close enough' to where it really should be based on other known
  reference data. You've given it a projection now, but it may not be
  the right one (just the one you want to use). The difference may be
  fractions of a meter or hundreds of kilometers. For your purposes it may not matter at all where the points are except relative to each other, or your accuracy requirements may deem whatever projection you used to be 'close enough'.